# Git Workflow Issue: git push, git reset --soft HEAD~1 and how to push updated code to new branch?

Tags: git, github

I am quite new to the git workflow. I made a mess and I need help to untangle it. This is what happened:

- I pushed files to the repo
- The component direction dramatically changed, so I decided I don’t want that commit to show in the repo anymore, but continue making changes to it
- I should have done more research and typed git revert, however instead I did git reset --soft HEAD~1
- I also unstaged all the files too (again didn't know about using --mixed command)
- Now I have files in my working area, but the commit is still in the repo

What I would like to do:

- Remove that commit completely from the repo (I am getting merge conflict now)
- Create a new branch, called feature
- And push new updated files to that branch instead

Any help is greatly appreciative.

Comment: You still could do a `revert` if you thing it's the right thing to do. Look at the command `reflog` to be able to reinstate how your history was. And then do your `revert` and (normal) `push`

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing resetting my reset with git reset HEAD@{1}; and then git reflog to get the specific commit number and git revet <commit>. Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

When you did `git reset`, you only undid the commit locally. You need to make the same change in remote as well.

1. Assuming you've already done `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, unstage the changes and clear your workflow using `git stash`.
2. Push to branch using `--force-with-lease` flag. This will forcefully push the git reset command and undo the commit for remote.

**WARNING**: Be very careful when using `--force-with-lease` flag, you may lose changes. It's always a good idea to backup your code incase things go wrong.

3. Create a new branch and unstash your changes. You now have your changes in a new branch.

Edit 1: This will work only if force pushes are allowed on the branch. If not, git revert is one option.

Edit 2: As pointed by [philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717372/philippe) `--force-with-lease` is a better approach.

More info about `--force-with-lease` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---no-force-with-lease).

Comment: `--force-with-lease` is most of the time much better than `-f`/`--force` and should be preferred to avoid loosing other developers commits

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about `--force-with-lease`.

Comment: Thank you Phillipe for taking the time to provide a solution. I was not comfortable doing the force flag (as i am still new to this and project is huge involving teams), so i just reverted my commit.